# Using Yacc and Lex to generate parse tree

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I've spent 6 hours writing a compiler for the productions below with Lex and Yacc. The terminal report `warning: empty rule for typed nonterminal, and no action` but I still can't find out what's wrong with my code.

```
P -> L | LP
L -> S
S -> ID = E | if C the S | if C then S else S
C -> E>E | E<E | E=E 
E -> E+T | E-T | T
T -> F | T*F | T/F
F -> (E)| ID
```

[yacc part code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/CallMeL/6544d8b2e14175778c747620c26442bf/raw/6dce9af5ef7b82a5bcfd832a5bf56d9dda2098a0/parser.y)

[lex part code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/CallMeL/5f2dacf39a51c3bb340bbd73bb0d7f21/raw/dce6347083e3715e75fb087d1fada4b8e60ae524/lexer.l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you get seems completely accurate:

```
F:      | …
```

`F` is a non-terminal; it has a type, and the first alternative is empty with no action. If a non-terminal has a production with no action, bison will automatically add the action `$$ = $1`, but it can't do that for an empty production, so it complains.

I assume the `|` in that line is a typo.

Comment: sorry I don't understand why the first alternative is empty for `F -> (E)` is to produce `(` terminal,  `E` non-terminal and `)` terminal.

Comment: @HannahChen: the first alternative starts after the colon (`:`) and ends before the (`|`), which is certainly empty. `'(' E ')'` is the second alternative. Bison and I are looking at your file, not your intentions. You should, too. That's why I quoted it in the answer. I know what you intended, which is why I think what you put in the bison file is a typo.